# Is there a way in Zod to create a new schema from an object schema by type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, zod

Let's say I have the following example schema:

```
const Z_GlobalSettings = z.object({
  crust: z.enum(["thin", "thick"]).default("thin"),
  toppings: z.array(z.string()).min(1).max(5).default(["cheese"]),
  sauce: z.enum(["marinara", "bbq", "ranch"]).default("marinara"),
  delivery_time: z.string().optional(),
  order_notes: z.string().max(50).optional(),
  contact_email: z.string().email().optional(),
  setting_1: z.boolean(),
  setting_2: z.boolean().optional(),
});

type GlobalSettings = z.infer<typeof Z_GlobalSettings>;
```

How can I programmatically extract the types that contain booleans, or whichever arbitrary type I'm looking for? For example, if I want the booleans from the schema, I'd want my new schema to look like:

```
const Z_OnlyBoolean = z.object({
  setting_1: z.boolean(),
  setting_2: z.boolean().optional(),
});
```

I was initially able to accomplish this using Typescript:

```js
type BooleanSettings = {
  [K in keyof GlobalSettings as GlobalSettings[K] extends boolean | undefined
    ? K
    : never]?: boolean;
};
```

However, this wasn't working when I wanted to differentiate between `z.string()` and `z.enum(["example1", "example2"])`, since they'd both come through as strings. This is why I'm hoping to find a way to filter a schema by type since Zod is keeping track of the difference between strings and enums, but the only way I can find in the documentation is to use the `.pick()` method and choose them one-by-one. This won't be great if I add properties in the future, since I'll need to update the filtered schema as well, and won't be great for usability since I'll need to make a new schema for every type I want to extract.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the type of the schema itself, rather than inferred schema type. This took me some time to figure out.

Because it looked from your question it's what you wanted, strings which are both nullable and can be undefined are included in the output, but `UnpackZodType` could be modified to change this behaviour easily.

```
const Z_GlobalSettings = z.object({
  crust: z.enum(['thin', 'thick']).default('thin'),
  toppings: z.array(z.string()).min(1).max(5).default(['cheese']),
  sauce: z.enum(['marinara', 'bbq', 'ranch']).default('marinara'),
  delivery_time: z.string().optional(),
  order_notes: z.string().max(50).optional(),
  contact_email: z.string().nullable().optional(),
  setting_1: z.boolean(),
  setting_2: z.boolean().optional(),
});

type GlobalSettings = z.infer<typeof Z_GlobalSettings>;

type UnpackZodType<T> = T extends z.ZodNullable<infer N>
  ? UnpackZodType<N>
  : T extends z.ZodOptional<infer N>
  ? UnpackZodType<N>
  : T;

type FilterByZodType<
  Schema extends z.ZodObject<Record<string, z.ZodTypeAny>>,
  Type extends z.ZodTypeAny
> = Pick<
  z.infer<Schema>,
  {
    [K in keyof Schema['shape']]-?: UnpackZodType<
      Schema['shape'][K]
    > extends Type
      ? K
      : never;
  }[keyof Schema['shape']]
>;


type StringSettings = FilterByZodType<typeof Z_GlobalSettings, z.ZodString>;
type BooleanSettings = FilterByZodType<typeof Z_GlobalSettings, z.ZodBoolean>;
```

This even retains the optional/nullables etc (TS strict mode required -- if you have it off, you will see just optionals here)!

[image]

[image]